# What magntitude does || W || refer to?

Tags: math, matrix, vector, statistics

I am trying to replicate an experiment in python, where it says that || W || = 1. I know that W is the magnitude, but which magnitude in context of vectors and matrices does this referes to exactly?

For instance say that i need to make sure that the following matrix || W || = 1:

```
array([[[1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6],
        [7, 8, 9]]])
```

What does it means to have said array to be || W || = 1?
is it column-wise, row-wise?

Basically, the reason i'm in doubt is because i have a matrix of 800x20, where each row is Xi, and i have another matrx of eigenvectors and eigen values that is 20x2 for example, in that formula where Y = W.t * xi.

Comment: Where did you see that?

Comment: There are multiple norms for both vectors and matrices: https://orion.math.iastate.edu/keinert/math507/notes/chapter5.pdf. Can't really tell which one you need without context.

Comment: Please provide a link, so we can see wider context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've only ever used ||W|| in weight regularization, and very briefly. It represents the norm of a 3D vector, which is essentially its magnitude as you've noted (when referring to a 2D vector).
But as the one comment says, there are multiple matrix norms that may exist.

Does that one represent the 'first norm' of a matrix? If so, you simply sum the columns and output the largest of those sums (a column-wise operation). That operation can also be done row-wise if you're determining the 'infinite norm'.

Some links that may help:

[http://www-solar.mcs.st-andrews.ac.uk/~clare/Lectures/num-analysis/Numan_chap1.pdf](http://www-solar.mcs.st-andrews.ac.uk/%7Eclare/Lectures/num-analysis/Numan_chap1.pdf)

http://www.maths.lth.se/na/courses/FMN081/FMN081-06/lecture6.pdf (for the basics)

https://cmci.colorado.edu/classes/INFO-4604/files/slides-6_regularization.pdf

It appears that NumPy has a way of calculating the matrix norms as well, so you don't need to manually code the process (never used it before):

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html

Answer (score 0):

Adding another answer so that things don't get lost.
Based on this paper:

http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e161/lectures/algebra/node12.html

They make use of a normalized vector to weigh the indices in the eigenvalue matrix accordingly (thus normalizing that matrix as well). The vector that they normalize appears to be the column with the greatest sum. However, it looks like there's a method of using both a normalized row and column vector as well.

It should be noted that ||I|| = 1 as a rule. Perhaps this is useful in your derivations.